# Save position slider after submission jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, slider

I want to save the positions of my slider after submission but i don't know how i can do. When i submit my form the slider reset position. I have 2 input (min and max), when i put value on the both, slider move but when i submit, the value are save but the slider reset his position. sorry for my english [before submission](https://pasteboard.co/JHlblAl.png) / [after submission](https://pasteboard.co/JHlbPHn.png)

```
 // 2 sliders
var $slider = $("#slider-range");
//Get min and max values
var priceMin = $slider.attr("data-price-min"),
priceMax = $slider.attr("data-price-max");


//Set min and max values where relevant
$("#price-filter-min, #price-filter-max").map(function(){
$(this).attr({
    "min": priceMin,
    "max": priceMax
});
});
$("#price-filter-min").attr({
"placeholder": "min " + priceMin,
// "value": priceMin
});
$("#price-filter-max").attr({
"placeholder": "max " + priceMax,
// "value": priceMax
});

$slider.slider({
range: true,
min: Math.max(priceMin, 0),
max: priceMax,
values: [priceMin, priceMax],
slide: function(event, ui) {
 $("#price-filter-min").val(ui.values[0]);
 $("#price-filter-max").val(ui.values[1]);
},
});

$("#price-filter-min, #price-filter-max").map(function(){
$(this).on("input", function() {
    updateSlider();
});
});
function updateSlider(){
$slider.slider("values", [$("#price-filter-min").val(), $("#price-filter-max").val()]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use **sessionStorage**?? after form submission

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("value", yourvalue);
```

then you can check if there is a value while reloading the page

```js
var slidervalue;
if(sessionStorage.getItem('value') != '' && sessionStorage.getItem('value') != undefined){
   slidervalue = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('value'))
} else {
   slidervalue = yourminvalue;
}
```

Comment: i don't know how session storage works, i will try but im not sure this is the answer to my question. thanks

Comment: sessionStorage is used to store values within a storage that can be accessed by your program from any instance of it. even after you leave the page it will still exist until you clear cache or cookies for your browser.
use **setItem()** to store value

`sessionStorage.setItem('name', value)`
use **getItem()** to retieve the value 
`sessionStorage.getItem('name')`